# Переделать методу transfer

Tags: java, arraylist

public class Bank implements BankingOperations, Observable {

```
private BankAccount bankAccount;


private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;


public Bank() {
    accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
}



public boolean hasAccount(BankAccount account) {
    for (BankAccount ba : accounts) {
        if (ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Stream API: anyMatch
public boolean hasAccountStream(BankAccount account) {
    return accounts.stream().anyMatch(ba -> ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount());
}


public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
    if (hasAccount(e)) {
        throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
    }
    accounts.add(e);
    System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
}


public void wyswietlListe(){
      for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
          System.out.println(bankAccount.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(accounts);
}


       @Override
       public void deposit(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
          if (amount < 0) {
              throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
       }
         // wyszukiwanie konta po numeru
         BankAccount account = accounts.get(nrAccount);

       if (null == account) {
           throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
            }
             account.deposit(amount);
          System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + "zl ,stan konta: " + account.getBalance() + "zl");
         if (amount >= 10000) {
              //+raport
         notifyObserverOffice(account, amount);
     }
   }

@Override
public void withdraw(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
    if (amount < 0) {
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
    }
    // wyszukiwanie konta po numeru
    BankAccount account = accounts.get(nrAccount);

    if (null == account) {
        throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
    } if (account.getBalance()>=amount) {
        account.withdraw(amount);
        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało obciązone o kwotę: " + amount + "zl ,stan konta: " + account.getBalance() + "zl");
        if (amount >= 10000) {
            //+raport
            notifyObserverOffice(account, amount);
        }
    }else {throw new NoMoneyEX("nie posiadas srodkow, podaj mniejszą kwote");}
}



@Override
public void transfer(int nrAccountFrom, int nrAccountTO, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
    if (amount <0){
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
            if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccountFrom) == true){
                if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount){
                    throw new NoMoneyEX("Saldo twojego konta nie pozwala zrobic przelew: balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                }else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount){
                for (int j = 0; j < accounts.size(); j++) {
                    if (accounts.get(j).equals(nrAccountTO)) {
                        accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                        accounts.get(j).deposit(amount);
                        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountFrom + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountTO + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                        if (amount >= 10000){
                            //raport
                            notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new NrAccountEX("Konto na kture chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                    }
                }
                }
            }else {
                throw new NrAccountEX("Konto z kturego chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
            }

        }
    }


     }
```

Comment: нужно переделать методу transfer на подобии amount и withdraw. Должны быть проверки на наличие аккаунта, баланс на аккаунте для перевода. Аккаунты находятся в Arraylist accounts. На вход подаются номера аккаунтов и сумма перевода. Если сумма больше 10 000 создается рапорт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема не с реализацией метода, а с пониманием самых базовых принципов программирования (начиная с ООП и его принципов, SOLID, GRASP итд). Вы абсолютно неправильно распределяете обязанности между классами и методами, это приводит к ужасным последствиям даже при такой тривиальной задаче.
К сожалению я вижу только один класс, в пределах которого невозможно привести вашу реализацию к минимально адекватному виду. Поэтому я вынужден добавить класс BankAccount. В случае, если там не реализованы все методы или не добавлены все поля, то вам придется добавить их самостоятельно.

Я использую lombok и аннотацию Data , вы можете убрать ее и добавить геттеры, сеттеры, toString и другие стандартные методы по необходимости

Итак, реализация:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Bank implements BankingOperations {
    
    private final Map<Integer, BankAccount> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    public BankAccount getAccount(int nrAccount) throws NrAccountEX {
        return Optional.of(accounts.get(nrAccount))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta"));
    }

    public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
        if (accounts.containsKey(e.getNrAccount())) throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
        accounts.put(e.getNrAccount(), e);
        System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
    }

    public void wyswietlListe() {
        accounts.values().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(int nrAccount, long amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        getAccount(nrAccount).deposit(amount);       
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(int nrAccount, long amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        getAccount(nrAccount).withdraw(amount);
    }

    @Override
    public void transfer(int nrAccountFrom, int nrAccountTO, long amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {        
        BankAccount accountFrom = getAccount(nrAccountFrom);
        BankAccount accountTO = getAccount(nrAccountTO);        
        accountFrom.withdraw(amount);
        accountTO.deposit(amount);
    }

}

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class BankAccount implements Observable{
    
    private final static double NOTIFICATION_LIMIT = 10_000;

    private int nrAccount;
    private long balance;

    public void deposit(long amount) throws NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        balance = balance + amount;
        notify(amount);
    }

    public void withdraw(long amount) throws NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        if (balance < amount) throw new NoMoneyEX("nie posiadas srodkow, podaj mniejszą kwote");
        balance = balance - amount;
        notify(amount);
    }
    
    private void notify(double amount) {
        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + "zl ,stan konta: " + balance + "zl");
        if (NOTIFICATION_LIMIT < amount) notify(amount);
    }
   
}
```

Как вы можете наблюдать, код уменьшился примерно в 3 раза, а упростился на порядок (в 10 раз) и добиться этого достаточно несложно.
Посему пробуйте разобраться и, если возникнут вопросы, смело задавайте.

P.S. никогда не считайте деньги в double либо любых других переменных с плавающей точкой по одной простой причине: они неточные. Никто не хочет знать, сколько приблизительно денег. А на большом количестве транзакций и на больших суммах эта самая неточность может повлечь огромные ущербы.

Comment: У меня все классы есть, и распределение между ними тоже, я скинул только класс с методами. Мне просто нужно переделать данный метод по примеру других и все

Comment: @Алексей если это нужно "просто переделать" да еще и есть пример, то в чем, собственно, вопрос?